# Simple nameless json array convert to mapped JS or PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have such json query result that I need to transform into a graph

```
[

    [1461931160000,583],
    [1461932077000,732.16668701172],
    [1461932587000,513.16668701‌​172],
    [1461933430000,675.66668701172],
    [1461934599000,462.66665649414],
    [14619357000‌​00,521.5]

]
```

The first values should become an array and the 2nd values another array.
I tried the jquery map() and Array.protoype.map() but I cannot figure it out.
Any PHP or JS method is deeply appreciated.

Comment: That doesn't look like a json string at all

Comment: That's not JSON, looks more like a `console.log` output. Well, actually, it looks more like a screenshot, which is pretty inconvenient for anyone trying to help out OP.

Comment: It is one object with arrays in it: [[1461931160000,583],[1461932077000,732.16668701172],[1461932587000,513.16668701172],[1461933430000,675.66668701172],[1461934599000,462.66665649414],[1461935700000,521.5]]

Comment: The screenshot comes from chrome's JSON VIEW extension. Who ever put  a minus to this question explain me why he dit it so I can move along wisely.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 2 dimensional array. To split it into columns, you can just iterate the array and push the values into new arrays

```
var data = [[1,2],[1,2]];
var firstValues=[];
var secondValues=[];
for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
    firstValues.push(data[i][0]);
    secondValues.push(data[i][1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One other way is using Array.prototype.reduce() as follows;

```js
var data = [

    [1461931160000,583],
    [1461932077000,732.16668701172],
    [1461932587000,513.16668701172],
    [1461933430000,675.66668701172],
    [1461934599000,462.66665649414],
    [1461935700000,521.5]

],
reduced = data.reduce((p,c) => (p[0].push(c[0]),p[1].push(c[1]),p) ,[[],[]]);

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(reduced,null,2) + "</pre>");
```